# Setting umask for su user command

Tags: sudo, su, umask, dash

In my system I set the umask for the user root to 0077 and for the non-root users to 0027 (via /etc/profile). This is working for the normal terminal logins. But if I login as root and change user with su command like this:

```
su user
umask
0077
```

I get the `0077` umask instead of `0027`. Is this normal behavior? how can I configure my umask `0027` setting for the `su` command to `0027`?
My default shell for the non-root users is the dash not the bash

Comment: are you using ubuntu ?

Comment: No its a Yocto build Linux system

Answer (score 1):

You could run `su - user` to get a login shell which probably will read `/etc/profile`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you switch the use it doesn't source the `profile` file so you have to put the `umask` command in place the will be sourced every time you switch the user.

Usually for setting a `umask` for every user individually we put it in `~/.bashrc` because it will be sourced every time you open new session for the user but in your case you have to look in you `~/.bashrc` file and figure out which file it source from `/etc/` when it called for example in `CentOS` the file is `/etc/bashrc` will be called every time by `~/.bashrc`

Comment: not if /bin/bash is not default shell
su - username -s /bin/bash 
resolve that